# Array.map returns ArraySeq?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, linear-algebra, dsl

I am making a small example of a linear algebra with sequential and parallel implementations. Below is the current code:

```
import util.Random
import System.currentTimeMillis
import actors.Futures._
import Numeric.Implicits._

object Parallel extends App{

  val rnd = new Random(1337)//Seeded RNG

  //Create 2 matrices with dimension NxN
  val N = 550
  val A:Array[Array[Double]] = Array.fill(N,N){ rnd.nextDouble }
  val B:Array[Array[Double]] = Array.fill(N,N){ rnd.nextDouble }

  //Time a call-by-name block and return milli-seconds
  def time(b: => Unit):Long = {
    val start = currentTimeMillis
    b
    currentTimeMillis-start
  }


  val sequentialProgram = new LinearAlgebra with SequentialLinearAlgebra {
    println("Sequential time: "+time { A * B } )
  }

  val parColProgram = new LinearAlgebra with ParColLinearAlgebra {
    println("ParCol time: "+time { A * B } )
  }

  val futureProgram = new LinearAlgebra with FutureLinearAlgebra {
    println("Future time: "+time { A * B } )
  }

}

//Interface, knows nothing about implementation
trait LinearAlgebra{

  type Vector[T] = Array[T]
  type Matrix[T] = Vector[Vector[T]]

  implicit class VectorOps[T:Numeric](v:Vector[T]){
    def dot(that:Vector[T]):T = innerProd(v,that)
  }
  implicit class MatrixOps[T:Numeric](m:Matrix[T]){
    def *(that:Matrix[T]):Matrix[T] = matMul(m,that)
  }

  //Functionality is deferred to implementing traits
  def innerProd[T:Numeric](a:Vector[T],b:Vector[T]):T
  def matMul[T:Numeric](A:Matrix[T],B:Matrix[T]):Matrix[T]
}

//Implements LinearAlgebra interface in a sequential fashion
trait SequentialLinearAlgebra extends LinearAlgebra {

  def innerProd[T:Numeric](a:Vector[T],b:Vector[T]) =
    ((a,b).zipped map (_*_)).sum

  def matMul[T:Numeric](A:Matrix[T],B:Matrix[T]) = {
      val Bt = B.transpose      
      A.map(row => Bt.map(col => row dot col)) 
    }

}

//Implements LinearAlgebra interface using parallel collections
trait ParColLinearAlgebra extends LinearAlgebra {

  def innerProd[T:Numeric](a:Vector[T],b:Vector[T]) =
    ((a,b).zipped map (_*_)).sum

  def matMul[T:Numeric](A:Matrix[T],B:Matrix[T]) = {
    val Bt = B.transpose
    (A.par map (row => Bt map (col => row dot col))).toArray
  }

}

//Implements LinearAlgebra interface using futures, i.e. explicit workload distribution
trait FutureLinearAlgebra extends LinearAlgebra {

  def innerProd[T:Numeric](a:Vector[T],b:Vector[T]) =
    ((a,b).zipped map (_*_)).sum

  def matMul[T:Numeric](A:Matrix[T],B:Matrix[T]) = {
      val Bt = B.transpose
      val res = A map ( row => future {Bt map (col => row dot col)}) 
      res.map(_.apply)
    }

}
```

The code seems correct to me, but I get the following errors:

```
fsc Parallel.scala
/home/felix/Documents/teaching/2014/dm509/scala/Parallel.scala:61: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[T]]
 required: SequentialLinearAlgebra.this.Matrix[T]
    (which expands to)  Array[Array[T]]
      A.map(row => Bt.map(col => row dot col)) 
           ^
/home/felix/Documents/teaching/2014/dm509/scala/Parallel.scala:71: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[T]]
 required: ParColLinearAlgebra.this.Matrix[T]
    (which expands to)  Array[Array[T]]
    (A.par map (row => Bt map (col => row dot col))).toArray
                                                     ^
/home/felix/Documents/teaching/2014/dm509/scala/Parallel.scala:82: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[T]]
 required: FutureLinearAlgebra.this.Matrix[T]
    (which expands to)  Array[Array[T]]
      res.map(_.apply)
             ^
three errors found
```

The problem seems to be that `Array.map` sometimes returns `ArraySeq` as oppposed to the expected `Array`. If I do a search-replace with Array and List, the program works as expected. The reason for moving to Array is that I wish to compare the efficiency to an imperative implementation, i.e., I need efficient random access.
Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Although the overhead will not be as low as an array, `Vector` does have O(1) random access. For high performance matrix operations, you probably don't want an array of arrays, but rather a single array with N * M elements where you computer the linear position based on the matrix dimensions. That also gives you the ability to have either row- or column-major organization (relevant for access locality). Since you're using a primitive type (`Double`), there's a very large advantage in space overhead with array over any other collection that will have to box the primitive values.

Comment: Yeah, I know one can go to great lengths to make cache efficient, platform aware implementations, but the idea here is to simply show simple parallelization strategies while comparing to a naïve imperative (triple nested whileloop) version. All this aside, the question is: why do the types not pan out?

Comment: Sorry, just to make clear: This is for educational purpose, the course is not on high-performance computing, I just need to give the students a sense of how parallelization can be done in a shared memory setting, while still giving them the sense that much more needs to be done for real high performance computing.

Comment: To help get an actual answer to your question, you should show the code that doesn't compile. It's clear from the compiler output that we're not seeing the whole program.

Comment: @RandallSchulz That's because of the little scrollbar widget thingy. /smiley

Comment: @RandallSchulz > It is that code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Array map returns ArraySeq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837799/scala-array-map-returns-arrayseq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context bound makes the difference:

```
scala> val as = Array.tabulate(10,10)((x,y)=>y)
as: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

scala> as map (x => x.sum)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45)

scala> def f[A: Numeric](as: Array[Array[A]]) = as map (x => x.sum)
f: [A](as: Array[Array[A]])(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[A])scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[A]

scala> def f[A](as: Array[Array[A]]) = as map (x => 42)
f: [A](as: Array[Array[A]])Array[Int]
```

Presumably it uses the fallback `CanBuildFrom` that yields a `Seq`.

Edit: to fix it, supply a `reflect.ClassTag[T]` so that it can create the `Array[T]` you want.

You'll need it on:

```
def matMul[T:Numeric](A:Matrix[T],B:Matrix[T])(implicit ev1: ClassTag[T])
```

and

```
implicit class MatrixOps[T:Numeric](m:Matrix[T])(implicit ev1: ClassTag[T])
```

Comment: Hmm that is horrible. I guess I could scrap the numeric typeclass for this example, but I thought it was a nice touch.

Comment: The question only asks why does it do that, but I added the more helpful fix, to enable you to upvote and accept. Do they ever call you `El Fix`?  It might make more sense to have `trait LinearAlgebra[A: Numeric]` etc.